# How to get this inequality given another inequality (norms and logarithms)

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

Suppose I have proved for all $f$ positive with $\lVert f \rVert_{L^2} = 1$ that
$$\int f^2\log(f) \leq -C_1\log(\epsilon) + \epsilon\lVert \nabla f \rVert_{L^2}^2.$$
I want to prove that for all $f$ with norm not necessarily $1$ that
$$\int f^2\log\left(\frac{|f|^2}{\lVert f \rVert_{L^2}^2}\right) \leq -C_1\log(\epsilon)\lVert f \rVert_{L^2}^2 + \epsilon\lVert \nabla f \rVert_{L^2}^2$$

How do I do this? I Tried taking $f=\frac{f}{\lVert f \rVert_{L^2}}$ but I just can't get the log in left hand side right.

Comment: Use $\log(x^2)=2\log(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can let $f \mapsto \frac{f}{\lVert f \rVert_{L^2}}$ and as @mathematician suggested, we can multiply by $2 \times \lVert f \rVert_{L^2}$.

Note that we get a factor of two on the right hand side so we do not get the desired inequality but a close enough one.